# How can I print to a specific xy coordinate

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to print to a specific xy coordinate in the console.  For instance I could print a letter X in the lower right corner I could set the cursor to (79,24) and print "X".  This has to be done using Ruby without any extras like curses.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that this is an XY-problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts `clear` + $/ * (24 - 1) + " " * (79 - 1) + "X"
```

Comment: So the only way this works is by clearing everything between 0,0 and the xy I specify?

Comment: Yes. You didn't particularly write it couldn't be.